# Connect to WiFi network without DHCP and private IP address in 169.254.0.0/16

Tags: android, flutter

I have a device that broadcasts a WiFi AP which doesn't have a DHCP server. Computers and iPhones can connect to it and end up with an IP in 169.254.x.y. Then, mDNS such as `device-name.local` are resolved and allow to use the web interface of the device to configure it (notably, send it the SSID/PSK of the target WiFi network to connect to).

For some reason, my Android devices (tested on Moto G6 Android 9 and Pixel 3 XL Android 11) fail to reach the IP state. They can associate with the AP but don't get a 169.254.x.y. IP. They usually keep mobile data active, or try to switch to another working AP.

When I disable mobile data and remove all known AP, they still won't get an IP after association.

When I manually set an IP in the same subnet (obtained by a computer that managed to connect to the IP and land in 169.254.x.y.), then it works! Name resolution doesn't work, but the Android device is able to reach the other device by using its IP address.

Now this is very bad, especially because I didn't find any stable API that didn't use reflection to set a static IP address when establishing a connection to a new AP.

Is there a way to connect to the AP and be able to reach the device using `whatever.local` without any interaction from the user?

My code basically does these steps, with a 15-time retry on each step if it fails (and start over from #1):

1. connect to SSID with

   ```
    WiFiForIoTPlugin.connect(ssid,
        password: 'XXXX', security: NetworkSecurity.WPA, joinOnce: true, withInternet: true))
   ```
2. get SSID with `WiFiForIoTPlugin.getSSID()`, check it matches the target
3. get RSSI and check it's not null or `== -127`
4. try to resolve `myhostname.local` (which works on Linux, MacOS, iOS but not on Android)
5. try to communicate with the device now that its host is resolved and we have IP connectivity

Comment: As I own the firmware on the device, I was able to add a DHCP daemon on that interface and this has fixed the issue. Android works well with this and understands that even though this is a network with no Internet, it can still access devices on its subnet directly (and use mobile data for the rest). This is a fix to my problem, but I had hoped that Android would behave like the other OSes I have tested (Windows, Linux, macOS, iOS) which all work with link-local addresses.

Comment: it could be that your android phone tries to use a ipV6 link local address, so potentially other phones/android versions could work, have you checked that?
Alternatively, if you do not have access to the AP to install services/demons, you should still be able to setup your own DHCP server and connect it to the AP (many customer devices do not block such traffic)

Comment: The 169.254.0.0/16 is the automatic private ip address range. When you don't have a DHCP server running on your network some devices will resort to picking a random ip address in that range. Not all devices will do this, and it can also be possible to disable apipa. This is not a setup you should be designing for. To answer your question, "Is there a way to connect to the AP and be able to reach the device using whatever.local without any interaction from the user?", yes: You can when you properly setup DHCP and DNS on your network

Comment: @Rob: no, my question was "Is there a way [...] without DHCP". Of course with DHCP the problem is solved.

Comment: Without DHCP you would need to statically assign an IP Address & DNS server on each of the devices. There would not be a way to do what you want using automatic private addressing and have it work reliably and consistently across different devices.